# Delayed touch release in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` in it. When running in the simulator, I drag the `UIScrollView` and it starts moving correctly, but when I release the drag, there's a small delay (around half a second) then the view continues moving to finish the momentum.

This delay only happens when the touch release happens in the view. So if I drag and release outside the simulator, there is no delay.

Here's the code for creating the `UIScrollView`:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
//scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
//scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

// Add some sub views here
// ...

// 2 pages
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

- I have not overridden any touch events in the app.
- I have not implemented any of the UIScrollViewDelegate methods.
- Enabling and disabling paging doesn't make a difference.
- I have not run this on a physical device, just in the simulator.

What's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend trying it on a real iOS device first. The iOS Simulator is not 100% accurate and may have bugs that do not exist on a real device.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm currently not a paid developer, so I can't run on a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else was wondering.

This is a side effect of using the touchpad on the MacBook. When doing three-finger dragging, the OS adds a delay after releasing to allow you to take your fingers up and quickly put them back down to continue dragging. This doesn't happen when using a mouse.

No problem with code or the simulator.

Silly me :)